# requirejs 2.1.11 + jquery mobile 1.4.2 throw error

Tags: jquery-mobile, requirejs

It seems that requireJS does not work properly with jquery mobile 1.4.2

in the app.js I have the minimum configuration for RequireJS 2.1.11

```
requirejs.config({
    'baseUrl': 'js',
    'paths': {
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery-1.10.2',
        'jquerymobile': 'lib/jquery_mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2'
    }
});
```

And then when I am trying to use jquerymobile dependancy I have:

```
define(['require', 'jquery', 'jquerymobile' ], function (require, $) {
   console.log(success)
})
```

This shows an error in the Chrome console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:63342/app/www/js/demos/js/jquery.js
Uncaught Error: Script error for: demos/js/jquery
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:141
```

This is caused by jquery mobile code:

```
(function ( root, doc, factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define( [ "demos/js/jquery" ], function ( $ ) {
            factory( $, root, doc );
            return $.mobile;
        });
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory( root.jQuery, root, doc );
    }
}
```

When I change with jquery mobile 1.3.2 it seems that require JS is working correctly. Is there a way to use requireJS with Jquery mobile 1.4.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the correct source. When I go straight to the [official source](https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js), I see:

```
(function ( root, doc, factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define( [ "jquery" ], function ( $ ) {
            factory( $, root, doc );
            return $.mobile;
        });
    } else {
```

This is exactly what I would expect: jQuery Mobile depends on `jquery`, which is the way you always should require jQuery with RequireJS.

The `demos/js/jquery` dependency that you see in the code you show in your question does not make much sense. It would be *possible* to make it work but it would require everybody who uses jQuery Mobile to go through an unnecessary configuration hoop. This is a big red flag that something is wrong.

Comment: thx correct! I copied the JS file under the demo folder in the zip archive and that had the reference to /demos/ .